# How to make Login without go through Database?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, authentication

I wanted to make a Login that never use Database and able to create Username and Password. So far I know there is possible to do it but I dunno how because I saw a guy use NOTEPAD to store Username and Password. His program can register new username and password and login with new username and password. He is using VB + visual studio 2010 to create the program. Anyone out there have idea How to do it?

Comment: It is a **very bad idea** to use plain text files to store usernames and passwords.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to store passwords at all, plain text or otherwise. Store a _hash_ of the password.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario there is a text file with usernames and passwords that is acting as a datasource instead of a database. So in the vb code you are

- Opening up the text file
- Parsing the file for the username (the key) and the password (the value)
- Closing the text file

Creating a new user involves:

- Opening up the text file
- Appending the new username and password to the text file
- Closing the text file

You might create a few problems with this approach: If one user is being authenticated when another user is being added you might find the text file locked by the other thread. Security is also an issue - but if that's what you want to do...

Comment: It is fine to me because this is University work. The requirement only need the program can run through Login and Fingerprint recognition only. Then is done! Thank You, Neil Thompson